# View PDF from file system in Telerik ReportViewer Control

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, telerik, controls

I have a c# WPF Application that is using Telerik ReportViewer. The ReportViewer Takes an IReportDocument. The problem is I have reports that have already been rendered and I want to display them. They are being saved as PDF files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. We would like to keep the control the same because we are custom handling the email button press to display a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned here:

[Display PDF in viewer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/display-pdf-in-viewer)

here:

[Loading PDF file into Telerik ReportViewer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/loading-pdf-file-into-telerik-reportviewer)

and here:

[Load PDF file in Telerik ReportViewer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/load-pdf-file-in-telerik-reportviewer)

This is not what ReportViewer is meant for. You can pass there XML or HTML file, but not rendered PDF. You should look for another component, in order to view rendered PDF, like one, mentioned here:

[How do I display a PDF directly in the browser without exporting first?](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/faq-display-pdf-browser)